# Abelian varieties with p-rank zero

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X$ be an abelian variety over a finite field of characteristic $p$ such that the $X[p]=0$. In other words, none of the Newton slopes are $0,1$.

**QUESTIONS.**

(a) Is it possible for the endomorphism algebra $End(X)$ to be commutative?

(b) If so, are there examples that are fairly easy to construct?

Comment: If you count only endomorphisms defined over the base field, it happens already for supersingular curves over $\mathbb F_p$.

Comment: Otherwise you have to go to genus $3$ surfaces. Examples are relatively easy to construct using Honda-Tate theory by fixing the characteristic polynomial of Frobenius - e.g. for most values of $a,b$, an abelian variety with characteristic polynomial $x^6 + a p x^4 - b p x^3  + a p^2 x^2 + p^3$ will have abelian endomorphism ring.

Comment: Apologies. I meant endomorphisms over the algebraic closure of the finite field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(a) Oh, yes. This is proven in a paper of Hendrik Lenstra and Frans Oort 
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404974900292 .

(b) A construction of the corresponding CM-field of endomorphisms is described in the paper mentioned above.